# Xamarin Package Installation Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When creating a new Blank Xamarin.Form Portable project in Visual Studio 2015, I get a "Package Installation Error"...

> Could not add all the required pacakges to the project. The following
> packages failed to install from C:....Xamarin\4.0.3.214\Packages:
>
> Xamarin.Form.2.0.0.6482: Could not install package Xamarin.Form.2.0.0.6482.
>
> You are trying to install this package into a
> project that targets .NETFramework,Version=v4.0

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms could not install package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958086/xamarin-forms-could-not-install-package)

Comment: I have the same exact issue!

Comment: Did anyone ever find an answer for this? I see the same issue come up for lots of people (including myself) but no one seems to have a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need to set the profile of the PCL correctly.

These are the options that I get when creating a new Xam.Forms app:

[image]

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958086/xamarin-forms-could-not-install-package) They have set the profile like so:

> I had a similar issue using Visual Studio and I've found that the following combination in the PCL works:
>
> - .NET Framework 4.5
> - Windows Phone Silverlight 8
> - Xamarin.Android
> - Xamarin.iOS

Comment: @Iain Smith we tried all of these but still its giving the same error