# Packages not getting installed with Xamarin forms application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have installed Xamarin forms, when I am trying to run the application , these missing dlls are showing, please help me how I can fix this issue.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\./ doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist. App1.Droid          
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\gurpreet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   App1.Droid          
Error       Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 24.2.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 24.2.1 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 24.2.1)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 24.2.1 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 24.2.1)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)'.           0
```

Comment: Do you need to run the Nuget package install?

Comment: Is this Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio? You have probably not installed the java SDK and android SDK & NDK. I can help you with installation if it is Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, im using visual studio for xamarin development, please share link if you have any.

Comment: I also installed the java sdk, but still not working, some packages are not fully installed that are in above list. Please guide me, How i can install these packages?

Answer (score 1):

your may be installed Nuget Packages for individual platform.

if not, Close your Visual Studio and reopen, it some times solve your issue. still your getting same issue then try to update  "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" & "Xamarin.Forms" Nuget Packages.

Don't forgot to "install packages" for entire solution.

Comment: I am trying to update these two packages, but not getting installed. Lets suppose i am trying to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, it needs dependent dlls. Installation get closed with exception.

Comment: Now again i have tried to install "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat"  but i am getting below error message. **Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.0.1.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0 
**

Comment: check out following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958086/xamarin-forms-could-not-install-package